# В чём отличие между 3мя способами инициализации строк?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

не понимаю, в чём принципиальное отличие между 3-мя способами, результат везде раз идентичный

```
int main()
{
    char *line1 = new char;
    line1 = "abc";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << *(line1++);
    }
    cout << endl;

    char *line2 = "def";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << *(line2++);
    }
    cout << endl;

    char *line3 = new char[3]; //тут понятно, что отличие от 1го способа в том, что заранее задан размер
    line3 = "ghi";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << *(line3++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Примеры взяты из Лафоре

Comment: Первый и третий с утечкой памяти, а главное сходство — все они в С++ некомпилируемы... Правильный либо `const char *line2 = "def";`, либо `char *line3 = new char[4]; strcpy(line3,"ghi");`.

Comment: В первом и третьем случае вы просто тут же забываете про ту память, которую выделили под строку, и присваиваете этому **указателю** ссылку на другую область памяти - с готовой строкой. Так не делают.

Comment: Приведенный код не собирается и никаких инициализаций строк в нем нет.

Comment: Нормальные люди пишут `std::string line = "abc";` и не мучаются.

Comment: разобрался, всем спасибо за комментарии !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `char *line1 = new char;` в данной строке вы выделяете память под одно значение char и записываете её адрес в указатель line1, затем в строке `line1 = "abc";` вы его затираете, что приводит к утечке памяти, и записываете в line1 адрес на начало строки "abc";
2. `char *line2 = "def";` этот вариант продолжает и дополняет первую проблему, этот код у вас, конечно, скомпилируется, но т.к. "def" является константой, при любой попытке изменения значений line2 ваша программа умрёт смертью храбрых, если вы и собирались line2 использовать как константу, то измените данную строку на `const char *line2 = "def";`
3. Та же проблема, что и в первом случае, вы выделяете память, а затем ссылку на неё затераете, ergo утечка памяти. Ну и не опять, а снова, проблема с "def" константой.

P.S. В соответсвтие с документацией ([тык](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)), до C++11 можно было присвоить string literal ("def") не константному char* неявным преобразованием (implicit conversion), эта возможность сохранялась для совместимости с C (т.е. `char *line2 = "def";` легально):

> String literals are convertible and assignable to non-const char* or wchar_t* in order to be compatible with C, where string literals are of types char[N] and wchar_t[N]. Such implicit conversion is deprecated.

Но, после C++11 такая запись будет приводить к ошибкам и требуется явное преобразование (т.е. `char *line2 = const_cast<char*> ("def");`)

> String literals are not convertible or assignable to non-const CharT*. An explicit cast (e.g. const_cast) must be used if such conversion is wanted.

Comment: Странное решение  `const char *line2 = (char*) "def";`. Как в анекдоте — или крестик сними, или трусы надень... :) Если есть `const` — зачем пр этом такое приведение к `char*`? Если без `const` — потенциальная проблема, так как позволит пытаться менять литерал через указатель на `char`. И, кстати, *Этот код у вас скомпилируется* — без изменений не скомпилируется...

Comment: @Harry Приведением я просто хотел показать, что в line2 записывается имеено указатель на "def", а не сама строка. По поводу вашего второго замечания, код скомпилируется, но с предупреждением, о том что приведение constant string к char* является устаревшим (deprecated).

Comment: Значит, компилятор старый... Это нарушение стандарта.

Comment: @Harry Да, как раз-таки предупреждение о нарушение стандарта он и выдаёт `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’`. Если я правильно понимаю, это не вызывает ошибок из-за обратной совместимости с C, а там выражение `char *line2 = "def";` было общепринятой практикой. Версия компилятора: g++ (Debian 13.2.0-5) 13.2.0

Comment: Ну, g++ и VLA разрешает :)

Comment: Рука тянется к минусу за `const char *line2 = (char*) "def";` Я бы два отдельных примера написал: с кастом и с const. А то создается ощущение, что нужны оба, а достаточно одного. *"как раз-таки предупреждение о нарушение стандарта он и выдаёт"* Это предупреждение - не то же самое, что deprecated. Deprecated было до C++11, а там окончательно забанили: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal Компиляторы со стандартными настройками много чего компилируют, с `-std=c++23 -pedantic-errors` попробуйте.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я подправил ответ... Кстати, при компиляции только с `-std=c++23` g++ выдаёт предупреждение, а с `-pedantic-errors` уже ошибку: `error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’`

Comment: разобрался, всем спасибо! примеры взяты из Лафоре, поэтому происходит нарушение стандарта